# Solve: $\ln x = e^x-e^1$ for $x$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I realise this might seem basic but the fact that this equation has both "ln" and e is confusing me because I cannot seem to make the equation have the same base:

$$\ln x = e^x-e^1$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!!

Comment: Hint:  one solution is obvious (just try a few simple values).  There is another, which as far as I can see can only be found numerically.

Comment: Certainly Mathematica doesn't know of a closed form for the other root.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: there are two positive real solutions which can be obtained by a numerical method,e.g. the Newton-Raphson method

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you can see ..One solution is obvious ..The other has to be found numerically...

Answer (score 0):

Start at $x_1=1/2$, then do $x_{n+1}=\exp(e^{x_n}-e)$

Comment: Newton-Raphson would be faster, viz. $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{\exp x_n-e-\ln x_n}{\exp x_n-x_n^{-1}}$.

Comment: @J.G. yes, but you have to study calculus for a year first, so it takes longer.

Comment: True, but anyone working with a problem containing $e^x$ probably did enough calculus already.

Answer (score 0):

You have been told already that numerical methods should be used for the non trivial root.

But you must be careful. Consider the function $$f(x)=\ln x - e^x+e$$ Its derivative $$f'(x)=\frac 1x-e^x$$ cancels at $x_*=W(1)$ where appears Lambert function. Numerically, this means $x_*\approx 0.567143$ which corresponds to a maximum by the second derivative test. So, in order to avoid problems (even very serious), you must search for a solution between $x=0$ and $x=x_*$.

Being lazy, let us start using $x_0=0.25$. Newton method will then provide the following iterates 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.25000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 0.23234075865580407607 \\
 2 & 0.23326694867597147957 \\
 3 & 0.23326974797292171657 \\
 4 & 0.23326974799836732850
\end{array}
\right)$$